# Unable to get data from database using hql in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, hql

I am using @Query in spring boot and want to get data from database. I have a table named data in my database. It contains images with their width and height. I want to multiply one image width with height then add this value to another image's width*height. I have defined a size 221841 and want to get images until the size is less than my defined size. I have written a query but not getting proper output. Please suggest me

Here is my **query**

```
@Transactional
public interface DataDao extends CrudRepository<Data, Long> {

@Query(getDataIdMax)
List<Data> getDataIdMax(Long post_id);

final String getDataIdMax= "select d from Data d,Data d1 where d.postId=?1 and d.width*d.height+d1.width*d1.height < 221841";
}
```

Here is my entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "data")
public class Data {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;


@Column(name="p_id")
private long postId;

@Column(name="data_name")
private String dataName;

@Column(name="width")
private long width;

@Column(name="height")
private long height;

//Getters and setters
}
```

My controller

```
@RequestMapping("/images/{post_id}")
@ResponseBody 
public List<Data> getDataIdMax(@PathVariable("post_id") long post_id,   HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException {

List<Data> postobj = dataDao.getDataIdMax(post_id);

return postobj;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What error are you getting? Or what value you are getting?

One suggestion: First try your SQL query directly in your database and check whether your query is correct or not.

Comment: query is not correct... i am unable to write query for my logic :(

Comment: My question is: which two images data you want to multiply, this is not the correct way to do it. data d and data d1 will point to the same table but when you say d1.width and d.widht it points to the same data,